# How can I verify a Facebook user access token in backend?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to verify a token sended by a frontend after a login proccess in Facebook.

After lots of ways trying and failing in my Clojure backend, I'm trying to do this using curl just to check if I'm doing this right.

First of all I execute the below `curl` to get my access token according to the documentation:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

The response has a token, ok.

After that I execute the bellow curl to debug the token frontend sended me in the input token param and the access token I just got before:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

This gave me an error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":TRACE_ID}

The error occurs even if I send my `app_id` and `app_secret` in the `access_token` according to the documentation. (`app_id|app_secret`)

I was just be able to succeed getting my `app access token` directly from Facebook developer page, inside my application in the token tool. In fact, using the debug token tool in Facebook developer page, I checked the access token that I got from the dev page and the one I got from the `curl`. The one that works is an `APP token` and the other is a `client token`.

So, what am I doing wrong? I'm getting the app access token wrong? I didn't see another way to do this in the documentation :(

Comment: Are you sure both tokens actually belong to the same app?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have only one app configured in Facebook dev page.

Comment: Works fine for me, both with the app token created by combining app id and secret, as well as with one explicitly requested using the first mentioned endpoint. In the debug tool both show as type “app” - if you are getting “client token” instead, maybe that indicates that you went wrong with the token creation somewhere.

Comment: Could be a configuration in application Facebook developer console?

Comment: The first curl I do gives me a Client token and not an app token :/